# good program design for global variables

Tags: python, global-variables

I have a master program, in which I would like to use a global variable, accross all other programs. I can't find the right way to do it (I can only think of overcomplicated solutions).

So for instance I tried this:

```
#master_prgm py
from global_vars import x,update
global_vars.update(1)

#global_vars
x=0
def update(y):
   x+=y
```

I thought x would be defined at the import of global_vars, but apparently it does not because I have the message "local variable 'x' referenced before assignment"

Would you see a nice way?

Comment: Every program that imports `global_vars` is going have its own copy of `global_vars.x`. Interprocess communication requires sockets, pipes, shared files, or something similar.

Comment: Using pure "global variables" and "good design" in the same sentence is kind of an oxymoron. Would classes count as being an "overly complicated" solution?

Comment: Using global variables is not considered good program design in Python. Many even consider it an anti-pattern. In most cases you can archive the same with classes and instance variables.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks, so how would you do that with classes and insances? And then why global variables is something that exists?

Answer (score 0):

A variable in python is a name in some namespace bound to an object. If I were to write

```
x = "foo"
y = x
x = "bar"
```

we wouldn't expect `y` to be "bar". After all, it is a unique variable assigned the object from `x`.

```
from global_vars import x
```

is similar. We now have two variables (1) `global_vars.x` in the global_vars namespace and (2) a separate and unique `x` in the local module namespace. An equivalent import shows this more dramatically

```
from global_vars import x as a_different_x
```

If you want to share `x`, even when updated, keep referring to it in the original namespace

```
import global_vars

#global_vars
global_vars.x=0
def update(y):
   global_vars.x+=y
    print
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like the function update to be in global vars and accessible by other functons as well

Comment: @kaleidoscop There is no such thing as a truly global variable, just variables in namespaces such as modules. The function updates `global_vars.x` and anybody who uses `global_vars.x` sees that update. Anybody who does `from global_vars import x` simply gets a new reference to whatever was in `x` at that moment in their module namespace. That it happens to be called "x" in two different namespaces doesn't mean its the same variable - its not.